# Migrating from Magento-1 to Magento-2 (while keeping the layout)

Tags: magento2, migration

I have developed a separate instance of a website on Magento 2 which uses a different layout. I would now like to move all of the information for the main website (Magento 1.9.1) to the new Magento 2.

Importing only the database doesn't work since there are differences in the modules and some of them cannot be removed from "Required".

Basically I need to move the whole installation, while somehow keeping the layout/modules on the secondary domain (the Magento 2).

Is this possible and if so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The layout structure of Magento 2 is very different from Magento 1.x

You will need thus to build a new theme from scratch in Magento 2 with the same look&feel.

Comment: Ah, I suspected so. Thank you for the input :)